# How to Hide Publishing wizard Options

Tags: publishing

In one of my project I have a requirement that I want to hide out of the box **publishing wizard** feature. I.e. Publish Related Items.

[image]

Comment: Did you try hiding it from Publish.xml file?

Comment: Thanks sumit for quick response. Can you help me where I can find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is in case of removing this, you should hide the checkbox from the `xml` that Sitecore uses to render the popup.

You can find this in `Publish.xml` file under the below location.

```
\wwwroot\<your-website-root>\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish
```

And you should use `Visible="false"` to hide the check box that you want. For example, I am using it to hide `Publish related items`.

So the code will be like this.

```
<Checkbox ID="PublishRelatedItems" Header="Publish related items" Visible="false"/>
```

And there is also an information icon that you should hide like this.

```
<div class="publish-wizard-tooltip" >
  <ThemedImage Src="office/16x16/information.png" Align="Center" Visible="false" />
  <Literal class="publish-wizard-tooltiptext" Text='${Translate.Text(Texts.PublishesAllReferencesToTheItemThisMayIncreaseTheTimeItTakesToPublish)}' />
</div>
```

Now the publish wizard will look like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's working . Thanks sumit

Comment: Doing it via security as in the other answer is better. It will make your upgrades easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this using Sitecore policies.

There is an item called `Can Publish Related Items` in the folder `/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies/Publish/` of the `Core` database:

[image: Policy item]

You can restrict access to this item for specific roles or delete/rename it if you want to disable it for all users. When Sitecore is unable to access this policy item, it hides the checkbox "Publish Related Items" from the publishing dialogue.